# Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I am running a stored procedure but while running it shows error like

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

I have set my web config like

```
   <add name="SAMPLECONNECTION" connectionString="Data Source=ADMIN\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PFGRT;Persist Security Info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;User ID=sa;connect Timeout =1000000;Password=PASSWORD"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I tried like set the `connect Timeout = 0;` also, but I get the same error.

How can I solve it?

My Stored Procedure calling class

```
public DataSet adFeedBackReportFacultyWise(string SetID, string FacultyID, string SubjectID,string groupid)
{
    DbUtil du = new DbUtil();
    Dictionary<string, SqlParameter> cmdParameters = new Dictionary<string, SqlParameter>();
    cmdParameters["SetID"] = new SqlParameter("SetID", SetID);
    cmdParameters["FacultyID"] = new SqlParameter("FacultyID", FacultyID);
    cmdParameters["SubjectID"] = new SqlParameter("SubjectID", SubjectID);
    cmdParameters["groupid"] = new SqlParameter("groupid", groupid);

    return du.ExecuteQuery("adFeedBackReportFacultyWise", cmdParameters);
}
```

My DButil Class is

```
public class DbUtil
{
    string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gatikkcmsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    public SqlDataAdapter ad;
    public DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    public DbUtil()
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gatikkcmsConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        cmd = null;
    }

    public SqlConnection getConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(connection);
    }
   public int ExecuteCommand(string storedProcName, Dictionary<string, SqlParameter> procParameter)
    {
        int rc;
        using (SqlConnection cn = getConnection())
        {
            cn.Open();
            // create a SQL command to execute the stored procedure
            using (SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = storedProcName;
                // assign parameters passed in to the command
                foreach (var procParameters in procParameter)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(procParameters.Value);
                }
                rc = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            cn.Close();
        }
        return rc;
    }
}
```

Comment: u using application blocks?

Comment: A `connection timeout` is different from a `command timeout`.  The former can be set in the connection string, but the latter will need to be applied programmatically to the command that's being executed.  That said, the default is, I think, 30 seconds - how long does this proc take to run?

Comment: Increase the `Connection Timeout`. By default it is 30 seconds. You can assign your own value to it.

Comment: @Brendan Green, about 1 minute

Comment: @Webruster, I am not aware about where to set it

Comment: Where is your store procedure? Plz add in que

Comment: @SemilSebastian What's the definition of `DbUtil`?  If it comes from a framework, which one?

Comment: @Brendan Green, Its my connection class

Comment: I guess then that internally you are creating some kind of `DbCommand` instance that ultimately executes the proc.  You should be able to set the command timeout there.

Comment: try to add this in your connection class  `sql.CommandTimeout = 120;`

Comment: `sql` is userdefined name .. please add your userdefined name over there

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx read the section on commandtimeout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is not the **connection timeout** (time taken to establish a connection to the database server), but rather the **command timeout** (time taken to execute the command).

In your `DbUtil` class, set the command timeout against the `SqlCommand` like so:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 120; //set timeout - use appropriate value
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = storedProcName;
    // assign parameters passed in to the command
    foreach (var procParameters in procParameter)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(procParameters.Value);
    }
    rc = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

It would be worthwhile checking the performance of the stored procedure as well.

Answer (score 0):

As you are facing a timout on your command, therefore you need to increase the timout of your [sql command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx). You can specify it in your command like this

```
// Setting command timeout to 2 minutes
cmd.CommandTimeout = 120;
```